# Firefox: calc() invalid property value

Tags: css, firefox, css-calc

I have an element with a line-height set with `calc()`:

```
line-height: calc(3rem / 2);
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/vLxZZd

It works fine in Chrome, but Firefox's Developer Tools says that it's an invalid property value.

I'm sure I'm missing something that should be obvious.

Just for reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc
- http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known issue. Firefox does not currently support `calc()` values on properties that accept either lengths or numbers, of which `line-height` is one such property. See [bug 594933](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=594933).

Since 3rem / 2 is exactly 1.5rem you can just hardcode that amount instead as a workaround.

Comment: Just checked caniuse.com and the bug is listed under Known Issues as well. So yes, Ghodmode, you did miss something :P